# Terraform s3 bucket lifecycle_rule overlapping prefixes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

What will happen if I apply to my `s3`-bucket multiple **lifecycle rules** to which do **overlap**?

I want to keep 7 days of old versions by default, but for a specific prefix I want it to be different (1 day).
Can I overwrite lifecycle rule for a sub-prefix just by adding a rule below?

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
  acl = "private"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    id = "clean_old_versions"
    prefix = ""
    enabled = true
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      days = 7
    }
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    id = "clean_old_versions_playground"
    prefix = "playground/"
    enabled = true
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      days = 1
    }
  }
```